# Reaching nullptr crashes program - Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary, nullptr

I wonder if there is any way (I think there is) to avoid program crash when while loop is reaching nullptr? I did method that passes to string values from Binary Search Tree, but the problem occures when there is no right or left child of parent. My method:

```
string to_string()
{
    stringstream ss;
    Node<T>* tmp = root;
    queue<Node<T>*> q;

    while (!q.empty() || tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            q.push(tmp);
            tmp = tmp->left_child;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = q.front();
            q.pop();
            ss << "Data: " << tmp->data << " Left child: " << tmp->left_child->data << " Right child: " << tmp->right_child->data << " \n";
            tmp = tmp->right_child;
        }
    }       
    return ss.str();
```

So basically I want to know how tell compiler that when it reaches nullptr I want it to print out some value or string or whatever instead of crashing. When I remove **->data** (tmp->right_child->data for example) it works fine, obviously.
Does anyone know the solution?
*thanks*

Comment: Looks like you're [looking for `if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, I guess. But I just can't figure out how to do it;) I wouldn't ask for that if that was that easy for me, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `ss << ...` statement reaches a leaf `Node*` whose `left_child` and/or `right_child` are null, it tries to access `data` that is invalid. You are not handling that condition, hence the crash, and why removing the `data` access makes the code work.

Try this instead:

```cpp
ss << "Data: " << tmp->data;
if (tmp->left_child != NULL) // <-- add this
    ss << " Left child: " << tmp->left_child->data;
if (tmp->right_child != NULL) // <-- add this
    ss << " Right child: " << tmp->right_child->data;
ss << " \n";
```

Comment: yeah, that works fine. I didn't think about it in that way, thank you!